# Как работать со вложенными словарями

Tags: python, list, словари

У меня есть два блока исходных данных:

```py
documents = [
    {'type': 'bird', 'number': '22', 'name': 'Кики'},
    {'type': 'dog', 'number': '1', 'name': 'Шарик'},
    {'type': 'cat', 'number': '13', 'name': 'Маруся'}
]

directories = {'1': ['22', '1'], '2': ['13'], '3': []}
```

Задача 1.
После ввода команды “p” пользователь должен получить имя животного по его номеру.

Задача 2.
После ввода команды “s” пользователь по номеру документа должен узнать, в какой директории он хранится

Задача 3.
После ввода команды “l” пользователь должен увидеть полную информацию по всем документам: комер, тип, имя и в какой директории хранится.

Я затормозила уже на первой задаче.

Использовала цикл `for` и пыталась вывести значения по ключам. Но максимум, что получила - имя первого животного в ответ на любой введённый номер.

Помогите, чем можете :) Можно (и нужно) вводить функции. Только не делайте пожалуйста длиннющие однострочные циклы - мне важно понять принцип алгоритма.

Comment: Насчёт 3 задачи. Пользователь должен увидеть всех животных, или только информацию по тому, номер которого он введет потом?

Comment: По всем. Вводит команду - получает номер документа и прочую инфу для каждого животного. Промежуточных команд нет: команда - и вся инфа по всем животным.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 1):

```
documents = [
    {'type': 'bird', 'number': '22', 'name': 'Кики'},
    {'type': 'dog', 'number': '1', 'name': 'Шарик'},
    {'type': 'cat', 'number': '13', 'name': 'Маруся'}
]

directories = {'1': ['22', '1'], '2': ['13'], '3': []}
```

Для первой задачи нам надо просто найти словарь, где ключ `number` равен введённому числу. Т.е. мы можем просто в цикле проходиться по каждому елементу в `documents` пока не найдём то, что нам нужно, либо использовать `filter` с условием.

```
p = input('command: ')
if p == 'p':
    num = input('number of animal: ')
    animal = list(filter(lambda e: e['number'] == num, documents))[0]
    print(animal['name']) # вывели имя животного
```

Для второй задачи действуем по тому же принципу. Но т.к. `directories` это словарь, а не список, мы должны проходиться по его ключах либо значениях этих ключей. Проще всего использовать метод `directories.items()`, который возвращает кортеж `(ключ, значение)`. И собственно потом уже проверять, есть ли во втором елементе этого кортежа значение введённое с клавиатуры (номер).

```
if p == 'c':
    num = input('number: ')
    dir = list(filter(lambda e: num in e[1], directories.items()))[0]
    print(dir[0]) # первый елемент, т.е. номер директории
```

С последним заданием всё еще проще. Если нам нужна информация по каждому животному отдельно, то просто в цикле проходимся по каждому елементу `documents` и ищем номер директории в которой это животное. Номер директории ищем как во втором примере, для каждого елемента `(ключ, значение)` словаря `directories` проверяем есть ли там номер нашего животного.

```
if p == 'l':
    for animal in documents:
        dir = list(filter(lambda e: animal['number'] in e[1], directories.items()))[0]
        animal['directory'] = dir[0]
        print(animal)

# command: l
# {'type': 'bird', 'number': '22', 'name': 'Кики', 'directory': '1'}
# {'type': 'dog', 'number': '1', 'name': 'Шарик', 'directory': '1'}
# {'type': 'cat', 'number': '13', 'name': 'Маруся', 'directory': '2'}
```

В итоге можно переписать все красиво:

```js
documents = [
    {'type': 'bird', 'number': '22', 'name': 'Кики'},
    {'type': 'dog', 'number': '1', 'name': 'Шарик'},
    {'type': 'cat', 'number': '13', 'name': 'Маруся'}
]

directories = {'1': ['22', '1'], '2': ['13'], '3': []}


def get_animal(number):
    return list(filter(lambda e: e['number'] == number, documents))[0]


def get_directory(number):
    return list(filter(lambda e: number in e[1], directories.items()))[0]


p = input('Команда: ')
if p == 'p':
    print(get_animal(input('Номер документа: ')))

if p == 'c':
    print(get_directory(input('Номер документа: '))[0])

if p == 'l':
    for animal in documents:
        print(animal, f"dir = {get_directory(animal['number'])[0]}")
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!!! Ещё вопрос: у меня с этими же условиями - ещё две задачи: по определённой команде добавить новую директорию и удалить директорию. Нюанс в том, что это задание я получила по теме "Функции". Но так и не поняла необходимости сюда функцию вводить, если вполне можно обойтись циклами. На ваш взгляд, использование функций в данном случае имеет смысл? Я пока не понимаю, какую функцию в данном можно вставить, чтобы укоротить и упростить цикл.

Comment: @ВикторияЗакирова, в этом примере, конечно же нет смысла использовать функцию. Но по мере увеличения программы код будет повторяться и выглядеть некрасиво и, возможно, будет смысл вынести всё это в функции.

Comment: @ВикторияЗакирова, даже если код не повторяется, имеет смысл давать имя куску кода, чтобы кратко описать, что в нем происходит, что на входе, и что в результате